# MercadoPago con Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mercadopago, xamarinforms

Buenas noches queridos compañeros, estoy hace días tratando de integrar un checkout de mercado pago para mi aplicación Cross-Platform Android y iOS.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente paquete de NuGet oficial de ellos:
https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-dotnet

Necesitaría que alguien me guíe o me muestre algún ejemplo utilizado para poder personalizarlo a mi manera..

Sinceramente estuve probando el ejemplo que dan en el github del sdk oficial que es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MercadoPago.Client.Payment;
using MercadoPago.Config;
using MercadoPago.Resource.Payment;

MercadoPagoConfig.AccessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

var request = new PaymentCreateRequest
{
    TransactionAmount = 10,
    Token = "CARD_TOKEN",
    Description = "Payment description",
    Installments = 1,
    PaymentMethodId = "visa",
    Payer = new PaymentPayerRequest
    {
        Email = "test.payer@email.com",
    }
};

var client = new PaymentClient();
Payment payment = await client.CreateAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine($"Payment ID: {payment.Id}");
```

No pude lograr conseguir el "Card Token", ni muchos menos simular un pago simple.
La documentación que brindan para C# o Xamarin Forms es muy pobre, por no decir, nula.

Espero que me puedan ayudar y guiarme en el camino correcto.
Saludos.
Gracias!

Comment: Mira esto, quizás te ayude: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-api/receiving-payment-by-card

Comment: @Mateo Sí, lo estuve viendo anteriormente, si bien la guía de pasos está bastante clara, está toda detallada en javascript y los métodos son muy distintos a los que tiene el sdk oficial de nuget.. por ejemplo: el sdk de .net no tiene un método setPublishableKey("YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY") y javascript sí. Y más adelante cuando crea el token de tarjeta también trabaja con eventos y varias cosas que son muy diferentes

Comment: De momento me es imposible reproducir en C# Xamarin Forms la forma de crear un Card Token especificada en javascript en el link compartido por @Mateo

Comment: A lo mejor esto te orienta un poco más: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/141617ea-2cfd-4240-bb6e-f0e78ecb0ecb/como-implementar-la-funcionalidad-de-mercadopago-en-mi-proyecto-con-visual-studio-con-c

Comment: Sí, también lo había visto.. realmente no es de mucha ayuda porque están utilizando la versión 1.2 y actualmente el paquete se encuentra en la 2.0 y también, muchos métodos ya están deprecados o no funcionan

Answer (score 0):

Yo acabo de integrar con Mercado pago. Lo hice con el modo [checkout pro](https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/introduction)
Primero tienes que generar una preferencia con esta API:

[https://api.mercadolibre.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=[aqui](https://api.mercadolibre.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=%5Baqui) tu token]

y le mandas tu preferencia como este en el body:

```
{
    "external_reference":"clay1",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "item-ID-1234",
            "title": "Mi producto",
            "currency_id": "ARS",
            "description": "Descripción del Item",
            "category_id": "art",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_price": 75.76
        }
    ],
    "back_urls":
    {
        "failure":"www.google.com",
        "pending":"www.google.com",
        "success":"www.google.com"
    },
    "auto_return":"approved"
}
```

Luego de que mandes tu preferencia te va a devolver un json y uno de sus propiedades es como este:

```
"sandbox_init_point": "https://sandbox.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=29929937-27037b0d-e71b-4f5f-a574-ec39e09c138621212"
```

Ahora desde tu .cs o clase en MVVM puedes usar xamarin.Essentials:

```
await Browser.OpenAsync(response.SandboxInitPoint);
```

abres la url que te es devuelva para que los lleves a la pagina de mercado pago.
Una vez completes todo no olvides cambiar la url a "init_point" el cual es la url de produccion.
Otro problema con el que choque fue el regreso a la app luego del pago. Para eso cree una web de redireccion porque el regreso desde mercado pago a la app no funciona.

Espero le pueda servir a alguien mas si fue muy tarde para ti. Saludos.